# How to update data azure SQL database using stream analytics?

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, azure-eventhub, azure-stream-analytics

How to update or delete data in azure sql DB using azure stream analytics

Comment: Were you able to resolve this somehow? I am also looking to use Azure SQL as the output sink of Stream analytics and struggle with this due to primary key violations.

Answer (score 0):

**Currently, Azure Stream Analytics (ASA) only supports inserting (appending) rows to SQL outputs (Azure SQL Databases, and Azure Synapse Analytics).**

You should consider to use workarounds to enable UPDATE, UPSERT, or MERGE on SQL databases, with Azure Functions as the intermediary layer.

You can find more information about such workarounds in [this MS article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/sql-database-upsert).

Answer (score 0):

I recently found the same problem in which I wanted to upsert directly from Stream Analytics into an Azure SQL (and I hadn't Azure Functions available due  to technical limitations). As a workaround, I created a trigger in the Azure SQL, that replaces INSERT with UPDATES. So, from Stream Analytics I just INSERT into the table, and Azure SQL replaces it with an UPDATE.

This is the trigger creation script:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.upsertTrigger  
ON dbo.table -- Set here the name of your table
INSTEAD OF INSERT  
AS  
BEGIN  
    SET NOCOUNT ON;  
  
    -- Iterate through each row in the inserted virtual table  
    DECLARE @YourPrimaryKeyColumn NVARCHAR(50); -- Set here the data type of your primary key
  
    DECLARE InsertedCursor CURSOR FOR  
    SELECT primary_key FROM inserted;  -- Replace here the name of your primary key column
  
    OPEN InsertedCursor;  
  
    FETCH NEXT FROM InsertedCursor INTO @YourPrimaryKeyColumn;  
  
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
    BEGIN   
        BEGIN  
            -- Perform an UPDATE if the row exists  
            UPDATE dbo.table -- Set here again the name of your table  
            SET  
                column_1 = i.column_1,  
                column_2 = i.column_2,
                ... -- Define the columns you want to replace 
            FROM dbo.table t  -- Here again your table
            INNER JOIN inserted i ON t.primary_key = i.primary_key -- Here again replace using the column name of your PK  
            WHERE t.primary_key = @YourPrimaryKeyColumn;  
        END  
  
        FETCH NEXT FROM InsertedCursor INTO @YourPrimaryKeyColumn;  
    END  
  
    CLOSE InsertedCursor;  
    DEALLOCATE InsertedCursor;  
END;
```

I hope this helps as a starting point. It is only valid if the row already exists, but you can adapt the logic to your needs.

Answer (score -2):

Firstly, we need to know what is [Azure Stream Analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-introduction).

An Azure Stream Analytics job consists of an input, query, and an output. Stream Analytics ingests data from Azure Event Hubs, Azure IoT Hub, or Azure Blob Storage. The query, which is based on SQL query language, can be used to easily filter, sort, aggregate, and join streaming data over a period of time. You can also extend this SQL language with JavaScript and C# user defined functions (UDFs). You can easily adjust the event ordering options and duration of time windows when preforming aggregation operations through simple language constructs and/or configurations.

Azure Stream Analytics now natively supports [Azure SQL Database as a source of reference data input](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/sql-reference-data#delta-query). Developers can author a **query** to extract the dataset from Azure SQL Database, and configure a refresh interval for scenarios that require slowly changing reference datasets.

That means that you can not insert or update data in azure sql DB using Azure Stream Analytics.

Azure Stream Analytics is not a database manage tool.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Azure SQL can be used as SA output.

Comment: "That means that you can not insert or update data in azure sql DB using Azure Stream Analytics.". This is untrue. You can insert data into your SQL database from SA. Whether you would want it is something else. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/sql-database-output